# ngModel not binding properly when using transclude: 'element'

Tags: angularjs

I am working with a way of wrapping my form inputs around a wrapper and have found that my ng-models stop working when doing so.

I have created a plunkr outlining the approach I have taken:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AUbB4BYGrdGr7Mhx0a9c?p=preview

Why is this so?

**Update (more details):**

The main idea of this is to be able to quickly create Bootstrap forms by allowing something that is semantically clean. Eg:

```
    <input ng-mode="newUser.firstName" name="firstName" first-name required></input>
```

And turn it into this:

```
    <div class="form-group has-feedback"
         ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.firstName.$invalid && !form.firstName.$pristine,
                     'has-success': form.firstName.$valid }">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </span>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="newUser.firstName"
                   name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required/>
        </div>
        <span class="form-control-feedback no-label">
            <i class="fa"
               ng-class="{ 'fa-ban': form.firstName.$invalid && !form.firstName.$pristine,
                           'fa-check': form.firstName.$valid }"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Bootstrap forms are really verbose and I tend to use the same styling over, and over.

This way I can develop reusable UI form components which later on can be hooked with validators or other services to enhance the UI.

Comment: Can you provide a more high-level explanation of what you're trying to do? It's confusing because it seems that you're trying to wrap your element in an `ng-transclude` directive; yet, there is no parent directive which uses transclusion.

Comment: Hey @MarcKline, I have updated it. Is this clearer?

Comment: I guess so.. I do understand why you might want to wrap the input element using `transclude: 'element'`, but I'm still unsure of why you'd want to wrap it with `<ng-transclude>`.

Comment: ng-transclude could be anything actually. I use it in my actual directive so I can do `template.find('ng-transclude')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `priority` for the directive to something higher than that of `ng-model`(priority: 0) to ensure that your directive runs first, thereby avoiding scoping issues:

```
demo.directive('wrapper', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 1,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude) {
      var template = angular.element('<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>');
      transclude(scope.$parent, function (clone) {
        template.append(clone);
        element.after(template);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[Fork of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vn1faRu3O1k5Q5oEReXT?p=preview)

Comment: I did not even know that `priority` was a directive property. Could you explain to me in more detail what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use `transclude: true` instead of `transclude: 'element'`

And what are you trying to do with the piece of code you have provided

Comment: Notice that when doing that, you are not wrapping it with <ng-transclude>. For this particular use case, transclude must be 'element'.